# Cannot have a pipe in an action expression ?

Tags: angular

I'm using this statement in my html template:

```
[(ngModel)]="tempProduct.unitprice | number : '1.2-2'"
```

But when i run it im getting this error in console:

> Cannot have a pipe in an action expression...

I need to use this number pipe but with `[(ngModel)]` or i will not get data. Any suggestion how can i fix this?? I tried with `[ngModel]` but when i do that i dont get data, its empty in html template.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Perhaps this should work for you:

```
[ngModel]="tempProduct.unitprice | number : '1.2-2'" (ngModelChange)="tempProduct.unitprice = $event"
```

This way "two-way"-binding is split in property-binding and event binding which allows more complex expressions.

Comment: same problem, i dont get data

Comment: Sorry, I have no way of knowing with the provided information. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: problem is that i had input type="number" when i removed that it works