# Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression

Tags: html, angular

I have this expression in my angular HTML form.

```
 <mat-form-field (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()" >
        <input id="StartDate" matInput placeholder="Start Date" name="start" [textMask]="mask"   [(ngModel)]="RecLoadData.startDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'" (ngModelChange)="RecLoadData.startDate=$event" (blur)="onBlurOpenAndCodeDate($event.target.value, 1)">
    </mat-form-field>
```

I keep getting an error saying:

```
Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column 25 in [RecLoadData.startDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'=$event] in c:/RecLoad/RecLoadAng/src/app/Recload/Recload.component.html@22:110ng(0)
Parser Error: Unexpected token , expected identifier or keyword at the end of the expression [RecLoadData.startDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'=$event] in c:/RecLoad/RecLoadAng/src/app/Recload/Recload.component.html@22:110ng(0)
```

I am already using (ngModelChange) which is suggested in another post. This post is not a duplicate.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot have a pipe in an action expression ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46040687/cannot-have-a-pipe-in-an-action-expression)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DatePipe` cannot be used with two-way data binding `[(ngModel)]="..."`. Since you already update the value with `(ngModelChange)`, you can display the date in the input element with one-way data binding, using `[ngModel]`. In the following code example, I update the value only when leaving the input field, with the `ngModel` option `updateOn: 'blur'`.

```html
<input [ngModel]="myDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'" 
       (ngModelChange)="onChangeDate($event)" 
       [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ... >
```

```js
onChangeDate(value) {
  this.myDate = new Date(value);
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gnna4s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

Comment: Thanks. As soon as I did one way data binding, it worked.